# jQuery check for adjacent selector

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, jquery-selectors

I am trying to check for the existence of an adjacent (next) selector but I am clearly writing it incorrectly...

My HTML

```
<div id="container">
<div class="about"></div>
<div class="related"></div>
</div>
```

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
console.log(jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass(".related"));
    if (jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass(".related"))
    {
        console.log("do something");
    }
});
```

My first console.log shows FALSE and my second isn't showing at all...

Comment: the second isn't showing because `jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass(".related")` is false.  It's not going inside your `if` block

Comment: Why would you expect the second console command to run if the first returned false, and that's the condition you're checking? Also you can use shorter syntax `jQuery(".about + .related"))`. You rep at 666 right now is scaring me away... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be without the dot. `hasClass` does not take a selector, but just the name of the class:

```
jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass("related")
```

Or alternatively:

```
jQuery("div.about").next('.related').length > 0
```

Comment: Wow thank you! I would have stared at this for the next 45 minutes without figuring that out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead.

```
jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass("related");
```

Just drop the `.`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `.` in your .hasClass selectors

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass("related"));
    if (jQuery("div.about").next().hasClass("related")) {
        console.log("do something");
    }
});
```